# Existence of convergent subsequence in $H^{k}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\Omega = \mathbb{T}$ is the $1$D torus. Consider a sequence of functions $\{ u_{n} \}_{n \ge 1}$ such that this sequence is

- Cauchy in $L^{2}(\Omega)$,
- bounded in $H^{1}(\Omega)$.

**Question 1:** Is it true that there exist a subsequence $u_{n_{j}}$ converging to some $u$ strongly in $H^{1}(\Omega)$?

I think the answer is yes, but I would be very grateful if someone could verify.

**My attempt:**

The first fact implies that there exists a subsequence $u_{n_{j}}$ and some $u \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ such that $u_{n_{j}} \to u$ strongly in $L^{2}(\Omega)$. The second fact implies that there exists a subsequence denoted again by $u_{n_{j}}$ for convenience and some $v \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ such that $u_{n_{j}} \rightharpoonup ^{*} v$ (weak*) in $H^{1}(\Omega)$.  But both convergences imply convergence in the sense of distributions. Since limits in $\mathcal{D}'$ are unique then we have $u = v$ in the distributional sense. However, since we know that $v \in H^{1}(\Omega)$, we must also have that $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$. To see this last fact more concretely, $u=v$ implies that the distributional derivatives also coincide, i.e. $u' = v'$. But here $v' \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ and so $u' \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ too.

**Question 2:**

If this argument is correct then surely we could say that in general if $\{u_{n}\}$ is Cauchy in $L^{2}$, bounded in $H^{k}$ then there is a subsequence $u_{n_{j}}$ converging to some $u$ in $H^{k}$? This kind of seems too good to be true, but I don't have a great intuition for weak* convergence so my scepticism may be unfounded.

Comment: There will not be in general a subsequence converging strongly in $H^1$. In the paragraph 'attempt' you correctly prove existence of subsequence with weak limit in $H^1$ and strong limit in $L^2$, and you argue equality of both limits. But strong convergence in $H^1$ is not mentioned/proven. In fact, if the claim would be true, then the space $H^1$ would be finite-dimensional.

Comment: @daw Ah yes I see. I was incorrectly assuming that the weak limit in $H^{1}$ and strong limit in $L^{2}$ coinciding implies that we have strong convergence in $H^{1}$. Why is it that this claim would imply $H^{1}$ is finite dimensional? Is it because it would imply that any bounded sequence has a convergent sequence which only holds true in finite dimensions? Here we have an extra assumption that the sequence is Cauchy in $L^{2}$, though.

Comment: Being bounded in $H^1$ "implies" (modulo subsequences) that you're Cauchy in $L^2$ by Rellich's compactness theorem. So any orthonormal basis of $H^1$ (or rather an appropriate subsequence of it) will be a counterexample.